# Installed/removed Gnome, but now my boot/shutdown screens are showing the Gnome desktop image instead of the default loading stuff

Tags: unity, boot, gnome, grub2, shutdown

I recently installed `gnome-shell` and `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`, but wasn't happy with Gnome & decided to switch back to Unity. I've got a small issue though: something changed with the Ubuntu boot/shutdown screens. Instead of the traditional screen (with the logo, dark bg, and loading "dots"), what I get first is a plain blue screen, no text or anything:

[image: Image: blue screen instead of the normal Ubuntu boot/loading screen]

That blue screen stays up for about 20s or so, and then it changes and shows this image for another 10s or so:

[image: Image: screen showing unwanted background image] (pretty sure this is the default gnome background image actually, vertical stripes with varying shades/fades of blue...)

And after that, it goes black for a second and then Unity Greeter loads, and everything else is fine from there. I've already uninstalled/purged `gnome-shell`, and also I've ran `sudo update-initramfs -u && sudo update-grub`. Any ideas as to how I can get the default Ubuntu loading/shutdown screens back? Thanks!

Edit: Using Ubuntu 13.04, and I've also tried running `dconf-tools reset -f /org/compiz/`, with no change.

Answer (score 1):

I have your solution! It comes in two parts.

First, you most likely need to reset unity, because Gnome probably wrought havoc on your icons and overall unity theme. To do that, you'll need to run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Then run this command to reset unity:

```
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

Now about that pesky boot animation that Gnome has changed on you. Download Plymouth Manager using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mefrio-g/plymouthmanager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install plymouth-manager
```

If for some reason you get an error message or it doesn't properly install, then download the install package from the hyperlink below and then call up the program from the unity lens.

[Plymouth Manager Download](https://launchpad.net/plymouth-manager/+download)

Now, simply select the first boot logo from the "themes" tab, and click "Apply." A small terminal window will pop up. Enter your root password, then type "11" to select "ubuntu-logo.plymouth."

Upon restarting your system, your default Ubuntu boot logo should be restored, and your Unity settings should be back to normal.

Oh! When you're done, you may find that your minimize/maximize buttons are still on the right side of the window. If this is the case, open Unity Tweak Tool, click "Window Controls" and toggle them back and forth until they are where they belong.

I hope you took this all as a learning experience, as I did. Have fun with Unity Tweak Tool!

Answer (score 0):

Try running `unity --reset` from a terminal. Keep that terminal open until you shutdown the computer. Then, it should be fine. 
Edit: Try getting into a text environment and Reinstalling Unity.

Comment: Thanks for the lead, unfortunately the `--reset` option is deprecated in Ubuntu >= 12.10. Tried running `dconf-tools` but no dice.